# Find the last active cell in a column over many rows of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of non-contiguous data in a table across 108 rows and 15 columns. I'm trying to find the last used cell in every row and paste it to another worksheet.
For example: row 3 last data on column J, row 5 column O...row 38 column I, and so on
I am very new to writing VBA, any help would be great
**EDITED**
This is what i have:

```
Sub Selectionoflastcell()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim ccol As Range
Dim i As Long

 With Worksheets("May-July Quarter").ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).ClearContents
   lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column

    Set colrange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lCol))
    i = 1
    For Each ccol In colrange
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ccol.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(lRow, ccol.Column).Value
        i = i + 1
     Next ccol
End With

End Sub
```

But it is just giving me the last value of each column from the bottom, if I change it to xltoLeft, I get only the first row

Comment: `Set LastCell = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)`... that finds the last cell in row 1 and should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Selectionoflastcell()

    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, rw As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("May-July Quarter")
    i = 1
    'loop over the table's rows
    For Each rw in ws.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.Rows
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = _
           ws.Cells(rw.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value
        i = i + 1
    Next ccol

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working now and has made my job so much easier.